# How to remove double quotations from inside value when importing csv into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, string, csv, bulk-load

I am using the code here to import a csv into a mysql table. It works great and ENCLOSED BY removes any double quotations.

My csv values are like "text text",123,"text text",456,"text text"

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
INTO TABLE '.$table.'
FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
ESCAPED BY \'"\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'
(location,rating,board etc)
```

I have just found that some values have double quotations, inside the main double quotations.

Like 3rd column here - "text text",123,"text "Special" text",456,"text text"

Which imports as - text text,123,text "Special text,456,text text

I have tried the ESCAPED BY as shown but cannot get it to remove the inner double quotations. It is in a wordpress environment but above code does work (apart from my problem).

Any idea help or ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the double quotes like this :

```php
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
INTO TABLE '.$table.'
FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
ESCAPED BY \'\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'
(location,rating,board etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You showed us this line from a CSV file

```
"text text",123,"text "Special" text",456,"text text"
```

Unfortunately, that's not well-formed CSV. `"` characters inside column values must be escaped. So for that line to be well-formed it must look like one of these.

```
"text text",123,"text ""Special"" text",456,"text text"
"text text",123,"text \"Special\" text",456,"text text"
```

If this were my project, I'd go back to where I got this bad CSV file and try to get a good one.

If that's not possible, and your file doesn't have any commas embedded in column values, you could try this load command, taking off the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` clause.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
INTO TABLE '.$table.'
FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
ESCAPED BY \'"\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'
(location,rating,board etc)
```

You'll then get some string values with `"` characters at their beginnings and ends. You can clean that up by queries like this

```
UPDATE table SET field = SUBSTRING(field,2) WHERE field LIKE '"%';
UPDATE table SET field = SUBSTRING(field, 1, LENGTH(field)-1) WHERE field LIKE '%"';
```

The first query takes off leading " signs, and the second one takes off trailing ones.